# Where do I install the Linux bootloader with this setup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot, boot-loader, elementary-os

```
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online         1863 GB  1862 GB        *
  Disk 2    Online          238 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online         7385 MB  7384 MB
  Disk 4    Online           57 GB    25 GB
```

I have windows installed on Disk 0. But, for some reason the Windows bootloader installed itself on Disk 1?

I'm wondering where I install the linux bootloader when I am asked? Last time I tried to install it in the same location as the Windows bootloader to replace it, and I had to reinstall Windows because I could no longer boot to it.

Also, is there a way to move the Windows bootloader to the same disk as the Windows OS? I have no idea why the Windows installer put the bootloader on a seperate hard drive. Makes 0 sense.